# Enable the Browser's Autocomplete in Onepage Checkout Form

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, forms, chrome-browser

How to enable autocomplete for the checkout form?
Currently my browser (chrome) does not store any input values...

Comment: Which fields are you talking about? Which browser? There is a CSS or form field attribute (don't remember properly) which you can use to influence autocomplete.

Comment: But this is more or less a browser-question. Maybe magento's field names are to strange for some browsers (because of the PHP arrays ... i.e. billing[firstname])

Comment: & did you try if it works on other shops? Your address etc. might just not be cached in your developer's machine?

Comment: Happends with chrome on http://demo.magentocommerce.com/ It can't be CSS and I don't see any autocomplete attribute, could be caused by JavaScript.

Comment: Confirmed. I had chrome://settings/autofill empty first, but after fixing this it still does not work. On other shops it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did the following on Magento 1.8.1

1. changed as described by Inchoo in billing.phtml. Don;t forget to change *both* in template/checkout/ and template/persistent

   `form id="co-billing-form" method="post" autocomplete="on" action=""`
2. Updated opcheckout.js

   `elements[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','on');`

This works fine now.

One thing we do see however. If you have some nice CSS set-up that add the checkmarks or other to validated fields is that the autocomplete overwrites this with the infamous yellow background

Answer (score 5):

Our friends over at Inchoo have a nice article on this along with a [fix](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/fix-chrome-autofill-issue-on-magento-checkout/). Basically, you just need to add a method to the form, either post or get.

In `template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` add `method="post"` in line 28:

```
<form id="co-billing-form" method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
    <ul class="form-list">
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento disables the automatic filling of some forms.

[image: Screenshot of demo.magentocommerce.com, checkout]

This is done by calls like `elements[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','off');`
 in `opcheckout.js`.

But even uncommenting this call did not make it work.

If you search the code for a RegEx `autocomplete.*off` there are many places where autocomplete is disabled.

There are browser plugins to override this - but I guess you want to make the shopping experience better for all customers, without the need to install a plugin ;-)

So there would be some debugging needed - please share your results!